# CATALINA_PID was set but the specified file does not exist

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, tomcat8, tomcat9

I was following this guide to setup tomcat on Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS Xenial (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-16-04).

Got to the point of the first launch:

```
sudo systemctl start tomcat
```

and received an error:

```
~$ sudo systemctl start tomcat
Job for tomcat.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status tomcat.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

journalctl -xe
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit tomcat.service has begun starting up.
Feb 27 15:23:42 76672.local startup.sh[20551]: Tomcat started.
Feb 27 15:23:42 76672.local shutdown.sh[20563]: $CATALINA_PID was set but the specified file does not exist. Is Tomcat running? Stop aborted.
Feb 27 15:23:42 76672.local systemd[1]: tomcat.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Feb 27 15:23:42 76672.local systemd[1]: Failed to start Tomcat 9 servlet container.
-- Subject: Unit tomcat.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit tomcat.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
```

`CATALINA_PID` expected to be in a directory `/opt/tomcat/latest/temp/tomcat.pid`

I gave rights to do everyone for everything for this dir `/opt/tomcat` and all subfolders/files:

```
~$ namei -l /opt/tomcat
f: /opt/tomcat
drwxr-xr-x root   root   /
drwxr-xr-x root   root   opt
drwxrwxrwx tomcat tomcat tomcat
```

Does anyone can point me to the possible solutions?

UPD:
Using `bin/startup.sh` Tomcat successfully starts.

Comment: Hi Maxim, can you check that the temp folder and pid file are present at the following path: CATALINA_PID=/opt/tomcat/temp/. I got this path from the link you mentioned

Comment: If the file does exist, try removing it then restarting tomcat

Comment: @HichemBOUSSETTA folder exist, inside it only empty (checked by nano) file safeToDelete.tmp

Comment: This is a working systemd init file that I am using with tomcat 8 installation. Can you try it? The difference is on the stopExec script:

`>[Unit]
>Description=Apache Tomcat 8.x
>Wants=syslog.target network.target
>After=syslog.target network.target

>[Service]
>Type=forking

>Environment=CATALINA_PID=/opt/tomcat/temp/tomcat.pid

>ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
>ExecStop=/bin/kill -15 $MAINPID
>PIDFile=/opt/tomcat/temp/tomcat.pid
>SuccessExitStatus=143

>User=tomcat
>Group=tomcat
>UMask=0007
>RestartSec=10
>Restart=always

>[Install]
>WantedBy=multi-user.target`

Comment: Another main difference is the "PIDFile=/opt/tomcat/temp/tomcat.pid". 
A guess this is the variable that tells systemd where to write the file, while the CATALINA_PID is meant for catalina.
Can you update your init script and restart the service?

Comment: @HichemBOUSSETTA with yours init file fails to start cause of exceeded timeout and reason `PID file /opt/tomcat/temp/tomcat.pid not readable (yet?) after start: No such file or directory`
I guess some setting on my Ubuntu set to not create .pid file. Tomorrow I would try on a new clear Ubuntu.

Comment: Okay, please let me know!

Comment: @HichemBOUSSETTA On a clear new Ubuntu 16 all worked fine. Yours script also worked.

Comment: perfect, thanks for the info! :-)

Answer (score 1):

When you use CATALINA_PID in tomcat.service file please make sure to use the path inside of the double-quotes.

```
Environment="CATALINA_PID=/opt/tomcat/latest/temp/tomcat.pid"
```

Like below

```
[Unit]
Description=Tomcat 9 servlet container
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking

User=tomcat
Group=tomcat

Environment="/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64"
Environment="JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom -Djava.awt.headless=true"

Environment="CATALINA_BASE=/opt/tomcat/"
Environment="CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat/"
Environment="CATALINA_PID=/opt/tomcat/temp/tomcat.pid"
Environment="CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms512M -Xmx1024M -server -XX:+UseParallelGC"

ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
ExecStop=/opt/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

congratulations!